# Problema com lógica de programação em Java

Tags: java, android

Boa tarde para todos,

comecei a duas semanas atras um sequencia de estudos sobre programação para Android. Estou estudando por este livro

http://novatec.com.br/livros/googleand/sumario9788575221860.pdf

comprei ele faz um tempo e graças a Deus cheguei finalmente na pagina 341 que é banco de dados.

tem uma classe chamado carro, eu entendo de orientação a objeto, mas nunca vi uma classe tão estranha como essa

```java
package com.example.googleplay.model;

import java.net.URI;

import android.content.ContentUris;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.BaseColumns;

public class Carro {
    public static String[] colunas = new String[] { Carros._ID, Carros.NOME,
            Carros.PLACA, Carros.ANO };

    public static final String AUTHORITY = "com.example.googleplay.model.carro";

    public long id;
    public String nome;
    public String placa;
    public int ano;

    public Carro() {

    }

    public Carro(String nome, String placa, int ano) {
        super();
        this.nome = nome;
        this.placa = placa;
        this.ano = ano;

    }

    public Carro(long id, String nome, String placa, int ano) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.nome = nome;
        this.placa = placa;
        this.ano = ano;

    }

    public static final class Carros implements BaseColumns {
        private Carros() {
        }
    }

    public static final Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://" + AUTHORITY
            + "/carros");
    public static final String CONTENT_TYPE = "vnd.android.curso.dir/vnd.google.carros";
    public static final String CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE = "vnd.android.curso.item/vnd.google.carros";
    public static final String DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER = "_id_ASC";

    public static final String NOME = "nome";
    public static final String ANO = "ano";
    public static final String PLACA = "placa";

    public static Uri getUriId() {
        Uri uriCarro = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Carros.CONTENT_URI, id);
        return uriCarro;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Nome: " + nome + ", Placa " + placa + ", Ano " + ano;
    }
}
```

Vou somente comentar as partes que ficaram em vermelho.

```java
public static String[] colunas = new String[] { Carros._ID, Carros.NOME,
        Carros.PLACA, Carros.ANO };
```

Para existir `Carros` era necessário que existisse uma classe chamada `Carros`, porém no projeto do livro não existe nenhuma classe chamada `Carros`, ele reconheceu somente `_ID`

A outra coisa mais estranha é que `Carros` conseguiu enxergar `_ID`.

Aí realmente não sei explicar.

Esse outro pedaço do código ficou também em vermelho:

```java
    public static Uri getUriId() {
        Uri uriCarro = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Carros.CONTENT_URI, id);
        return uriCarro;
    }
```

O que ficou em vermelho foi o `CONTENT`.

Eu entendo que é complicado ter que ajudar sem ter acesso ao livro, mas mesmo assim eu postei, espero receber alguma ajuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Algumas linhas não estão onde deveriam estar. A classe `Carros` ficou muito curta e contendo somente um construtor. Todas as linhas abaixo dela pertencem na verdade ao interior da classe `Carros`. A classe `Carros` portanto ficaria assim:

```
public static final class Carros implements BaseColumns {
    private Carros() {
    }

    public static final Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://" + AUTHORITY
            + "/carros");
    public static final String CONTENT_TYPE = "vnd.android.curso.dir/vnd.google.carros";
    public static final String CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE = "vnd.android.curso.item/vnd.google.carros";
    public static final String DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER = "_id_ASC";

    public static final String NOME = "nome";
    public static final String ANO = "ano";
    public static final String PLACA = "placa";

    public static Uri getUriId() {
        Uri uriCarro = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Carros.CONTENT_URI, id);
        return uriCarro;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Nome: " + nome + ", Placa " + placa + ", Ano " + ano;
    }
}
```

Note que agora todos os campos `CONTENT_URI`, `CONTENT_TYPE`, bem como `NOME`, `ANO`, `PLACA`, etc. pertencem à classe `Carros` e portanto a IDE reconhecerá os campos `Carros.NOME`, `Carros.CONTENT_URI`, etc. que antes estavam em vermelho.

Note também que por implementar a interface `BaseColumns`, a classe `Carros` adquiriu um campo `_ID`, que é o `Carros._ID` visto mais no começo do código postado na pergunta.

Comment: nossa mano! perfeito, funcionou, muito obrigado.